# Determining if a possible new entry already exists in a dataset

Tags: c#, performance, console

For example, if I have the following data table layout:

```
dt.Columns.Add("ticketid", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("createtime", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("creator", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ticketText", typeof(string));
```

If I want to add a new entry I need to make sure that there exists none already that has the same primary key (`ticketid`, `createtime`, `creator`).

The check is as follows:

```
if (
    dt.Rows.Count <= 0 ||
    (
        dt.Rows.Count > 0 &&
                    null == dt.AsEnumerable().Where
                        (
                            r => r.Field<int>("ticketid") == newEntry.TicketId
                                && DateTime.Equals(r.Field<DateTime>("createtime"), newEntry.CreateTime)
                                && r.creator == newEntry.Creator
                         )
                         .FirstOrDefault()
   ))
```

The code does what it is meant for, BUT my problem is that it is SLOW. In my case I need to read 2 million entries from the file and put them into the database as fast as possible at which this code fails (as soon as I use the code the runtime goes from just 1 minute to over 30 minutes). Is there any faster way to do this?

Site-note: the datatable is read from a file and the above is a check to make sure the data is ok before it is bulk inserted into the db.

Example with happenings:

```
if (
    dt.Rows.Count <= 0 ||
    (
        dt.Rows.Count > 0 &&
                    null == dt.AsEnumerable().Where
                        (
                            r => r.Field<int>("ticketid") == newEntry.TicketId
                                && DateTime.Equals(r.Field<DateTime>("createtime"), newEntry.CreateTime)
                                && r.creator == newEntry.Creator
                         )
                         .FirstOrDefault()
   ))
{
    // No duplicate found so insert the data into the data table
   dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {newEntry.TicketId, newEntry.CreateTime, newEntry.Creator});
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like the addon I added on the bottom?

Comment: kk if any more info is needed or could help just let me know (wasn't and am not sure how much is needed, so put in the infos I thought as being needed but as we have seen not necessarily a 100% hit on what info is needed or not)

Comment: One alternative approach could be to use a stream-based solution instead of a data table.. that would, at the very least, prevent you from having to store all of the records in memory at once, which could potentially increase the performance of your code. You may also want to consider an enumerable instead of the data size is not important, as an enumerable would ensure that all operations on the data (filter/map/contains) are executed in a single iteration. These would both drastically improve performance. Don't use DataTables for data comprehensions.

Comment: Hmm would that not postbone parts of the original problem? Atm I'm using the datatable to make bulk inserts into a database where ticketid, createtime and creator are primary keys and which naturally fails for identical entries. If I use a stream approach then I would have less entries taht I transmit per insert and additionally I would have to let the database tell me which are duplicates and thus should not be transmitted to it. or am I mistaken?

Comment: It looks like you're only checking that the `newEntry` primary key isn't in the data table - is that right?

Comment: It depends where your bottleneck is. If your bottleneck is the DataTable doing comprehensions (which it likely is), then it can be as simple as just running all of the filtering/transformation operations outside of the DataTable. If this is the case, an Enumerable-based approach would likely be better. You are right in assuming you might want to bulk-insert, and reducing the number of round trips would be helpful, however there are two potential bottlenecks here - I/O and CPU. You'll likely hit an I/O bottleneck due to write speed limitations to SQL, however we can reduce the CPU one easily.

Comment: @RobH correct I'm just checking if the entry (the primary key to be exact) is not in the data table so far.

Comment: @Heslacher no the whole definition of the datatable is as in the code example above. I just defined the columns themselves. Nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Introduce a new object:

```
public class PrimaryKey
{
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }

    public PrimaryKey(int ticketId, DateTime createTime, string creator)
    {
        TicketId = ticketId;
        CreateTime = createTime;
        Creator = creator;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + TicketId.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + CreateTime.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 7) + Creator.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object value)
    {
        var other = value as PrimaryKey;
        return other != null 
             && other.TicketId == TicketId 
             // ... etc.
    }
}
```

Use this in a hashset:

```
// right at the beginning...
var dedupeList = new Hashset<PrimaryKey>();
// Populate hashset from data table 

if (dedupeList.Add(new PrimaryKey(newEntry.TicketId, newEntry.CreateTime, newEntry.Creator))
{
    // New
}
else
{
    // Already added.
}
```

You wont have to search through the whole data table each time which should save a lot of time when the data table is large. However, you will use more memory.

Comment: The datatable can be about 200k entries large. So in essence the hashset does the whole "already exists" calculation and ignores all possible entries if they are existent already. What about the bulkinsert? A hashset per se can't be bulkinserted can it? Does that mean in the end I would have to retransform it into a datatable for a bulk insert?

Comment: @Thomas - Well, you'd keep the hashset in addition to the datatable. Heslacher's answer using the PrimaryKeys property of the datatable is a much better idea.

Comment: Is there any possible reason for this variant to fail? I tried to do it the same way with putting the add to the dt into the "new" part but a few times I suddenly get duplicates still.

Comment: I even tried:             return (
                _TicketId.GetHashCode().ToString()
                + _CreateTime.GetHashCode().ToString()
                + _Creator.ToString().GetHashCode().ToString()
            ).GetHashCode();  but a few times I still get into the "new" part despite the entry already existing in the datatable

Comment: If I use instead: myHashSet.Add(newEntry.TicketId.ToString()+newEntry.CreateTime.ToString()+newEntry.Creator.ToString())  in the if it works. Any idea there?

Comment: Either the Equals or GetHashCode methods could be wrong - I wrote them directly on here so the code is all untested/compiled.

Answer (score 3):

If we use a more classic variant of just a `if..else if..` construct we see that there is something just not needed

```
if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
{
    // No duplicate found so insert the data into the data table
   dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {newEntry.TicketId, newEntry.CreateTime, newEntry.Creator});
} 
else if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 &&
                    null == dt.AsEnumerable().Where
                        (
                            r => r.Field<int>("ticketid") == newEntry.TicketId
                                && DateTime.Equals(r.Field<DateTime>("createtime"), newEntry.CreateTime)
                                && r.creator == newEntry.Creator
                         )
                         .FirstOrDefault())
{

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {newEntry.TicketId, newEntry.CreateTime, newEntry.Creator});
}
```

So no matter if the datatable contains zero rows or more than zero rows a new row should be added. The only penalty would be for the very first time where the datatable contains no rows at all. So skipping the check about about any rows will get you a micro optimization like so

```
if (null == dt.AsEnumerable().Where
                    (
                        r => r.Field<int>("ticketid") == newEntry.TicketId
                            && DateTime.Equals(r.Field<DateTime>("createtime"), newEntry.CreateTime)
                            && r.creator == newEntry.Creator
                     )
                     .FirstOrDefault())
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {newEntry.TicketId, newEntry.CreateTime, newEntry.Creator});
}
```

By using the [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h39yfbd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the `DataRowCollection` and setting the [`PrimaryKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `DataTable dt` will at least make your code clearer and maybe faster too but you need to measure this by yourself.

Comment: It looks like the data table creates an index of sorts over the primary key columns - this is a really good answer.